# Connecting to MySQL from Java 7

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to connect to a MySQL database from java using the following code:

```
Connection connection = null;
try {
    connection = DriverManager
    .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database","user", "password");
} catch (SQLException e) {
    System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
}
```

If I compile it with Java 7 I get the following error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1121)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:355)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2479)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2516)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2301)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:834)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:416)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:317)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:579)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:221)
    at jobimtext.util.db.DatabaseConnection.openConnection(DatabaseConnection.java:44)
    at jobimtext.util.db.DatabaseResource.connect(DatabaseResource.java:154)
    at jobimtext.thesaurus.distributional.DatabaseThesaurusDatastructure.connect(DatabaseThesaurusDatastructure.java:83)
    at jobimtext.example.demo.IThesaurusDatastructureSimpleDistSimProb.<init>(IThesaurusDatastructureSimpleDistSimProb.java:36)
    at jobimtext.example.demo.DistThresaurus.inizializeDT(DistThresaurus.java:49)
    at jobimtext.example.demo.HolingInput$4.actionPerformed(HolingInput.java:544)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:723)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:696)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:693)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Malformed reply from SOCKS server
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.readSocksReply(SocksSocketImpl.java:128)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:459)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:241)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:259)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:305)
    ... 56 more
```

if I change the compilation environment to Java 6 everything works fine. 
Someone knows if there is an incompatibility between Java 7 and JDBC?
I use the last version of the JDBC connector: mysql-connector-java-5.1.29-bin.jar

Thank you in advanced,
Silvia

Comment: is your databaseName 'database' ??

Comment: I use java 7 and connector 5.1.22 without problems

Comment: your stacktrace shows `Malformed reply from SOCKS server` do you use a socks server to connect to localhost?? Seems like a runtime environment issue, nothings to do with the compiler

Comment: How do I check if I use a sock server? I don't think I use one...

Answer (score 0):

Load jdbc Driver and try it again.

```
Connection connection = null;
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
    connection = DriverManager
    .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database","user", "password");
} catch (SQLException e) {
    System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("Drive Class Not Found.");
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
Connection conn = null;
Statement stmt = null;
try {
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
   conn = DriverManager.getConnection("DB_URL", "USER", "PASSWORD");
   stmt = conn.createStatement();
   String sql = "ANY_QUERY";
   stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
} catch (SQLException se) {
   se.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Using your code I get java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for <database_name>

Comment: @Silviutza: All right. Let's try to analyse the problem, to narrow the potential problem sources!

1. Which database would you like to use? And which version?
2. Which version of connector would you like to use?